# html5 impact and questions

Tags: html

I keep hearing about html5 and seen on other questions/answers on this site that the current browsers do not yet support it...what I know:

- it has potential to replace flash and silverlight
- Google seems to be building new systems to take advantage of it
  (is that correct?)

What I don't know (which is a lot, but will limit it to some points of interest):

- how will existing sites work within a html5 browser (backward compatible?)
- is Flash/Silerlight really gone? will they be supported? (I'm sure adobe will not be happy)
- is javascript impacted? improved? will jquery still work?
- is there a good site listing (high level down) what the html code impacts are?

Answer (score 4):

W3C has a working draft of the [differences between HTML 4 and 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/).

Answer (score 3):

> Google seems to be building new
>   systems to take advantage of it (is
>   that correct?)

***Correct***

[Google Bets Big on HTML 5: News from Google I/O](http://radar.oreilly.com/2009/05/google-bets-big-on-html-5.html)

[HTML5 and The Future of the Web](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/16/html5-and-the-future-of-the-web/)

[HTML 5 is a mess. Now what?](http://www.zeldman.com/2009/07/16/html-5-is-a-mess-now-what/)

Answer (score 3):

http://html5doctor.com/ is probably a good place to answer a lot of that.

Stop thinking about it as a new version. Think of it as just another step, building on what we have and introducing some new elements that let us do new stuff.

Read up on the new elements and what browser support they have, then start using them where they help you (remembering to use the right doctype).

Answer (score 2):

To answer just one question:

> "is Flash/Silerlight really gone? will
>   they be supported? (I'm sure adobe
>   will not be happy)"

Yes, they will be supported, since HTML5 still has the [OBJECT](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/object.html) tag and this is what is used to embed external content (such as Flash etc).

Answer (score 1):

For starters, it can work in older browsers. I've got it working in most major browsers in a reasonable span of versions: http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/

Flash and Silverlight will still be a part of the internet, but what they want to do is make it possible to have video content (for example) that doesn't need a plug-in to play it back. The idea is to pick a format that all browsers will support (this is more difficult than it sounds as the codecs might require licensing, or if they don't - might not be that good).

ALL browsers that support HTML5 will also display HTML4.01 and XHTML websites.

JavaScript and jQuery WILL continue to work.

Check out the http://www.w3.org/ website for the full specifications (in draft).

Answer (score 0):

> - how will existing sites work within a html5 browser (backward compatible?)

Just fine. HTML5 is, as far as possible, backwards-compatible. Of course, some new HTML5 tags/APIs don’t work in older browsers (although [many, like the new form field types, degrade gracefully](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/forms.html#type-email)), but much of HTML5 merely specifies, and builds on, how existing browsers parse HTML.

> - is Flash/Silverlight really gone? will they be supported? (I'm sure adobe will not be happy)

Adobe and Microsoft haven’t cancelled work on Flash and Silverlight, and no browser-makers (not even Apple) have said they’re removing their plugin APIs. So no, Flash and Silverlight are not gone.

> - is javascript impacted? improved?

The HTML5 spec both defines the DOM interface for HTML (which previous HTML specs didn’t do), and adds new browser JavaScript APIs (e.g. for `data-` attributes and geolocation). JavaScript the *language* isn’t affected though, as it’s specified in the [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)

> - will jquery still work?

Yes.

> - is there a good site listing (high level down) what the html code impacts are?

You don’t have to change any HTML code for it to continue to work.

As mentioned in other answers, the W3C has a decent document of the changes from HTML4:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/

And Dive into HTML5 is a great intro if you’re familiar with HTML 4, especially it’s introductory “5 things you should know” chapter:

- http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/
- http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/introduction.html